# How to remove html tags and trim the characters to 250 in Objective C

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I am displaying html data in webView (lot of content).Now i want to remove all the tags and trim the content to only 250 charecters and display in my Web-view.

Thanks In Advance....

Answer (score 2):

Included this function in the class.

in .h

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString;
```

in .m

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString 
{
  NSMutableString *outString;

  if (inputString)
  {
    outString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString];

    if ([inputString length] > 0)
    {
      NSRange r;

      while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
      {
        [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
      }      
    }
  }

  return outString; 
}
```

the call

```
  NSString *plainString = [self stringByStrippingHTML:inputHTMLString ];


    NSString *rangedString = [plainString substringToIndex:249];  //0 to 249 makes it 250 characters
```

Comment: @AppleDelegate Thanks for the solution. Its works perfectly to remove html tags. Can you tell me how can I replace <ol> & <li> from html contents with the actual number ?