# Replace <ol> & <li> tags from html code with number in iOS 6

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, ios6

I am getting html code from server & I want to display it in UITextView. I need to parse the html & show plain text in UITextView. I am using below code to parse html from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894955/how-to-remove-html-tags-and-trim-the-characters-to-250-in-objective-c)

Now I need to replace the `li` tag with the actual numbers . How can I do that ?
e.g. Input

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Output should be

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk

Comment: What do you mean by `actual numbers`?

Comment: Why don't you display it in a web view instead?

Comment: I can't display it in web view as it shows the contents in too small font. User needs to zoom in / out.

Comment: You can create your own CSS and add it to the HTML before the web view shows it, depending on the content of the HTML in the first place. Manually parsing HTML to produce plain text is hard. You'd need to write... UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you Function with following and pass your HTML string snippet that you have posted.

```
NSString *str = @"<ol>"
"<li>Coffee</li>"
"<li>Tea</li>"
"<li>Milk</li>"
"</ol>";

[self stringByStrippingHTML:str];
```

Function to replace string and Generate Desire output

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString
{
    NSMutableString *outString;

    if (inputString)
    {
        outString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString];

        if ([inputString length] > 0)
        {
            NSRange r;
            int index = 1;
            while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
            {
                if([[outString substringWithRange:r] isEqualToString:@"<li>"])
                {
                    outString = [[outString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %d. ",index++]] mutableCopy];
                }
                else
                    [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
            }
        }
    }
    return outString; 
}
```