# ios replace substring by new substring

Tags: html, ios, iframe, nsstring, substring

I have a string like below -

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body>

<p>***Some Text***.</p>

<p><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.some-domain.com/embed/mwOFWJUOpv8" width="600"></iframe></p></body>
```

I want to replace some of parameters in the `iframe` tag at the bottom of string as -

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="new vlaue" src="//www.some-domain.com/embed/mwOFWJUOpv8" width="new value"></iframe>
```

I can successfully grab out string starting from `"<iframe"` to `"</iframe>"` with the required changes. I am getting problem to replace that whole `<iframe ...</iframe>` with new string.

So my result should be like this -

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>

    <p>***Some Text***.</p>

    <p><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="new vlaue" src="//www.some-domain.com/embed/mwOFWJUOpv8" width="new value"></iframe></p></body>
```

**EDIT** : -  I have followed [this](https://freshmob.com.au/how-to-finding-and-replacing-strings-within-a-string-in-objective-c/) approach, but could not replace whole `iframe` tag in string.

Please help me out!

Comment: check this answer, similar but same approach can be used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207919/replace-ol-li-tags-from-html-code-with-number-in-ios-6

Comment: @JayahariV : can u illustrate EXACT approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try like this. Suppose str is the grabbed out string mentioned in your post.

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"width=\"600\"" withString:@"width=\"new value\""];
```

**Edit**

```
NSString *theStr= @"<iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"360\" src=\"//www.some-domain.com/embed/mwOFWJUOpv8\" width=\"600\"></iframe>";
NSString *replacedStr = [theStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"width=\"600\"" withString:@"width=\"new value\""];

NSRange range1 = [sourceStr rangeOfString:@"<iframe"];
NSRange range2 = [sourceStr rangeOfString:@"iframe>"];

NSRange range3 = NSMakeRange(range1.location, range2.location + range2.length - range1.location);

NSString *finalStr = [sourceStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range3 withString:replacedStr];
```

Comment: I can grab out substring, and make changes as I want successfully, problem I am getting is to replace that grabbed substring in original string!